# How to Display Related Products Horizontally in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I have looked everywhere! I want to display 3-4 related products on the page in a horizontal line. Right now they are in their default state in a vertical line due to me moving it from the right sidebar to the content area. It would look great horizontally and visitors would not have to scroll to find products they like.

Also how do you change the block title "Related Products" to something like "May We Also Recommend:"?

Comment: Have you tried ignoring Magento for this and just changing the page's CSS?

Answer (score 2):

To change titles and labels a good trick to know is [Inline Translation](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/).

For the products layout you only need to know a little CSS. Search the web for "css horizontal list".

Answer (score 1):

So instead of using "related products" tab (in admin -> manage products), I used the "upsell products" tab and chose products in there. Then i changed the title through:
    /public_html/store/app/design/frontend/default/storedesign/template/catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml

No one will know the difference :) Changing the CSS did not work for me, and I know enough CSS to change it but it seemed like it was coded in. Magento has way too many files to stress myself over it.